# index.html not set as default in subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've created a subdomain such as sub.website.co.uk

However it's not resolving at the index.html - I'm aware I need to add some code to a htaccess file.

One thing I'm not sure of is does the htaccess file go in the root of the domain or inside the subdomain folder?

I've tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^sub/index\.html
```

Note: if i go to sub.domain.co.uk/index.html it works just isn't automatically resolving when I go to sub.domain.co.uk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.htaccess can go in any directory you want and it will effect all subdirectories recursively.

You could put them in all of your directories if you wanted to.

You can add the following line to your .htaccess (in the directory of your subdomain):

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

That will fix your problem.

Comment: Can that command exist in a htaccess file on it's on or does it need syntax surrounding it? i.e. <IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>

Comment: should be fine just like that. try it.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work - Should I restart apache?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Tried it incognito mode and worked straight away, damn browser cache.